# Web site/app - Real-Time Charting Advice (mySQL, JS, PHP?)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, charts

I'm working on a project to create real-time charts from data in an SQL database.  I've done a lot of research on JS charting libraries and have picked out a few good ones.

My problem is that I'm not sure how to get started with linking the SQL data to the web app/site.

My HTML and CSS are fine.  I'm coming on with JS and we have software that provides me with necessary SQL query code.

**Where is the gap in my knowledge?  Is it necessary to learn PHP in order to get this working? How about C#?**

My solution will currently be a locally hosted site, running on a networked computer (not currently got server space).  The solution I have already uses Excel to query the database and runs a ton of macros to generate static charts every ten minutes.  This works, but I'd like to create something far more flexible, robust and interactive.

**Could anybody point me to any online resources that may help me?  I like ChartJS but any open-source charting library will do.  I'm hoping there's a great tutorial somewhere that covers SQL to real-time charts but I just can't find one...**

Comment: Sorry, this is possibly fairly basic stuff but I'm struggling to find that jump-off point to get started.

Comment: want to make charts?

Comment: Yup.  Real-time charts :)

Comment: see: http://www.highcharts.com/demo

Comment: i think this is what you want: http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/dynamic-update

Comment: That's kind of what I need.  My problem with the examples on a lot of these sites is that they are taking the plot points from a randomiser coded in JS.  I'd like to find out how to replace that randomiser with quite a lot of data that comes from an SQL database.  I'm struggling to find a helpful tutorial but maybe one does exist...

Answer (score 0):

If you want a real time charting you need to receive information from the DB almost every second. So sending a bunch of requests is not the best way to do this. You probably need to read about websockets and how do they work. Here is an [example](http://www.phpbuilder.com/articles/application-architecture/optimization/creating-real-time-applications-with-php-and-websockets.html) but you may find a lot more in google. If you don't want to do it with PHP, I can assure you that it would be far more easier with node.js